# Maintaining progress of the CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a cron job set up on the Kubernetes cluster to process millions of records from the database. Sometimes pod corresponding to the cron job gets Evicted or OOM Killed. Now the issue I am facing is whenever this cron job starts again it processes all those records from the beginning.

Just wanted to understand how should I approach storing the progress of this cron job somewhere. Let's say I store it in a database then how frequent should I make a db call to store the state?

Comment: Try to base your next iteration on the timestamp or UUID of the rows fetched already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend fixing OOM issue instead of finding work arounds. I've listed my thoughts on both.

**Fixing OOM**:
Assuming Cronjob is processing millions of records and it is hitting OOM issue, This mostly due to a memory leak. I would check if certain data structures/resources are being released after being done with it. Another way to approach is to increase the memory.

**Work around:**
If you are using database, it doesn't make much sense to introduce another technology just to save the progress. You can create a table for cronjob progress, and update the table after processing a batch of records.  You can update the table with pagination number or offset.

Answer (score 1):

> Maintaining progress of the CronJob

You can [check the job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/_print/#running-the-job) by running `kubectl describe <your_job>`, but this could be not a solution for your situation.

> Now the issue I am facing is whenever this cron job starts again it processes all those records from the beginning.

This is for the correct operation of [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). This is for the correct operation of CronJob. You need to know that CronJob only performs certain tasks in a timely manner and does not interfere with them anymore. The solution to your problem will be to interfere with your script which is run by CronJob. User  [Rakesh Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2777988/rakesh-gupta) has good mentioned in the comment:

> Try to base your next iteration on the timestamp or UUID of the rows fetched already

Generally you have to change your process which is working on the database. You can actually use timestamp or UUID for this. Basically you need to find an identifier that you can easily check before running your process. Then your process will start running from a specific location instead of all over again. Another solution may be to increase the available RAM if the process dies through OOM.

Answer (score 1):

i know i am a bit late to the party, suggestion from [Rakesh gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2777988/rakesh-gupta) & [Mikolaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15407542/miko%C5%82aj-g%C5%82odziak) are pretty good.

You either extend the resource limit or use DB.

i am not sure about the architecture of actual app which you have, you can also use the **Redis** **database** or Redis deployment as a side option. (Here i am not suggesting to change database or deploy but if you are using planning to use Redis in the future thn)

When your cronjobs run it's dump the records to **Redis** and **cronjob** process one by one records from the **Queue** inside the **Redis** database. This is a good option as not many **Db calls** will be there to the **main** **database**.

i am not sure you are on which language but this library is a good example to use with **Redis** and manage **Queue** : https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

Using this you can manage the **Redis** **Queue** and process the records with minimal **DB** calls and changes.